# Create separate variables from table1 object

Tags: r

I use the createTableOne function from the tableOne package. I enjoy it a lot.
For ease of access in R markdown I would like to deploy the list object into separate variables.

For example:
if I get a table:

```
      0   1
Var1 12   15
var2 85   32
```

I would like to spread into the following variables:

```
Var1_0 = 12
Var1_1 = 15
Var2_0 = 85
Var1_1 = 32
```

Comment: Can you please update with a small dataset and how you applied the `CreateTableOne`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the structure of the table, we can `unclass` the output to return the `list`, extract the component 'ContTable', which is again a `list`, so we loop over the `list` with `lapply`, and then get the row, column names to extract individual components ('n', 'mean', 'sd'), format the output with `sprintf` for certain components and return as a `list`.  To make the names  to `n_1`, `n_2`, etc. loop over the `list` with `Map`, set the names by `paste`ing and then use `list2env` to create objects in the global env (not recommended though)

```
library(tableone)    
lst1 <- unclass(table2)
lst2 <- lapply(unclass(lst1$ContTable), function(x)
    list(n = x[1, "n"], age = sprintf('%f (%0.2f)', x['age', 'mean'], 
    x['age', 'sd']),  time = sprintf('%f (%0.2f)', x['time', 'mean'], 
            x['time', 'sd'])))

Map(function(x, y) list2env(setNames(x, paste0(names(x), "_", y)),
              .GlobalEnv),  lst2, names(lst2))
```

-output

```
n_1
#[1] 138
n_2
#[1] 90
age_1
#[1] "63.340580 (9.14)"
age_2
#[1] "61.077778 (8.85)"
time_1
#[1] "283.231884 (213.05)"
time_2
#[1] "338.966667 (203.47)"
```

#### data

```
vars <- c("age","ph.ecog","time") 
catvars <- c("ph.ecog") 
table2 <- CreateTableOne(vars = vars, factorVars = catvars,
           data = lung, strata = "sex")
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I get most of it.
and I was wandering about a more general solution - such that if there are 20 variables you won't have to write them all one by one in the function

Comment: Interesting.
dput is too long to past in a comment. It's a list of 3 lists.
What version of r are you using.

This is the package in question: 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableone/vignettes/introduction.html

Comment: Yes, that's the one I meant. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Try this:
vars <- c("age","ph.ecog","time")
catvars <- c("ph.ecog")
CreateTableOne(vars = vars, factorVars = catvars,data = lung, strata = "sex")

Just for a sample

Comment: n_1 - 138
n_2 - 90
age_1 = 63.34 (9.14)
age_2 = 61.08 (8.85)
...
time_2 = 338.97(203.47)

Comment: Yes, but it is one for the relation of Var_1 and Var_2. So it can take the name of Var_P (like a third column)

Comment: Works amazingly. Thanks!

Comment: I will try to understand what you did and extrapolate to a general use case. Could you shed some light on the logic you used?

Comment: Thanks! much appreciated!!